# Battery usage by running application in Android

Tags: android

i am looking for battery usage by application in android.How can i achieve it programmatically? i want for wifi GPS.

Your help will be appreciated..

thank you.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Did you ever look into android sdk tools !! that means you have already look into it. So now tell us how can we do? common on any hint. "what have you tried ?" does not fit everywhere

Comment: @Sameer mind your attitude. OP does not show any attempt on trying on coding, which obviously "violate" Stack Overflow's FAQ. (p.s. I'm an Android developer)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Look at commons-ware answer, even he is prime contributor  on SO, he simply gave the answer. You should see the answer availability, then comment

Answer (score 2):

> i am looking for battery usage by application in android.How can i achieve it programmatically?

You don't. This is not available via the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I would start off here and get the current battery life, battery status intent : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Then use the API to get more specific for apps. I will have a look to see if I can see anything.

batterystats.bin file in the data/system/ directory has battery information. There isn't an API, you need to do this with your own build of the platform. Source: https://plus.google.com/u/0/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT